# Strange Angular 2 behavior with button click event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two very simple methods in my .ts file:

```
editLocation(index) {}

deleteLocation(index) { 
    this.locations.splice(index, 1); 
}
```

html counterpart calls these method when buttons are clicked:

```
<button (click)="editLocation(i)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Edit</button>
<button (click)="deleteLocation(i)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

"Delete" button works fine, quickly deletes what I need and shows updated list of "locations". Now, with "Edit" button I wanted to implement a different behavior. But, whatever I put in this method, after the code is executed, it thinks for a bit and redirects to a previous page. I deleted everything from the edit method (it is now empty as you can see above) and it still redirects to a previous page. 
However, if I add `this.locations.splice(index, 1);` to the "edit" method it behaves just like "delete" method and does not redirect anywhere. 
What can be wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: can you show the whole HTML code ?

Comment: That's basically the whole code I have now that relates to these 2 buttons. Otherwise it is 2000 lines of code))

Comment: that's what i want to know , verify if you have them in a form so they work as submit , and maybe it calls the method that deletes items for each submit

Comment: Ok, so I've changed button to span and it started working, still confused that delete is okey, but edit is not...

Comment: Button's default type is `submit`. To prevent this you have to add `type="button"` to Button tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can add type="button" to it, to be sure that button is not acting as submit or other event:

```
<button type="button" (click)="editLocation(i)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. This exact suggestion didn't work, but, following this train of thoughts I've changed button to span and it started working: <span (click)="editLocationAcuteSDH(i)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Edit</span>